# Websocket handshake unexpected 404 error - tomcat7

Tags: java, eclipse, websocket, tomcat7, raspberry-pi

Been looking at similar answers and so far mine hasn't replicated the same so I'm posting my question on here.

I tried my application on my other computer (same file and everything, just different IP address) and it works fine. The second I move it to my tomcat server (which is running fine, hits server startup and everything) it displays this when I debug in chrome:

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.1.12:8080/WebMobileGroupChatServer/chat?name=asdf' failed: Error     during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404`

I've seen the same error code in other questions, pointing to duplicate api's in WEB-INF or in the xml but this doesn't have a web.xml, and it works fine on the eclipse server on my desktop, but when I run the server on my RPi, it won't run.

I can make it to the tomcat home page, so I know it's set up correctly. I just need help finding what the problem is.

Do I need to go through the ./configure process for installation? I don't remember having to do that last time when it worked before, but let me know asap. Been a problem for a while now.

Comment: I it also Tomcat on the working computer? Which version? What do you mean by "eclipse server"?

Comment: The eclipse server is the tomcat server running on eclipse, which is the same version as the server running on my raspberry pi: tomcat 7.0.59